# Volume of cone with two different radius

Tags: geometry

If top radius of a cone **R1** , bottom radius **R2** (where **R1>R2**), total height **h** and another height **p** (where **p<=h**)

Then how can I calculate the volume of lower part with height of **p** ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Volume of the (complete) cone of height `h` and radius `R1`: `V1 = Pi R1^2 h / 3` [*]

Volume of the bottom (complete) cone of height `h - p` and radius `R2`: `V2 = Pi R2^2 (h - p) / 3`

Volume of the capped cone of height `p` and top radius `R1` and bottom radius `R2`: `V = V1 - V2 = Pi / 3 [R1^2 h - R2^2 (h - p)]`

[*]: Compute the integral of `S(z) dz` from `0` to `h` (where `S(z)` is the surface of the section at height `z`, `S(0) = 0` and `S(h) = Pi R^2`).